# Importing modules - Python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of `testcases` on my `integration` framework. I'm loading those modules dynamically using `importlib` library in Python. So, inside `framework.py` I have:

```
def load_class(self, filename, class_str):
    try:
        class_data = filename.split(".")
        current_path = "{0}.{1}".format(self.root, class_data[0])
        module_path = self.format_path(current_path)
        module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
        return getattr(module, class_str)
    except Exception, e:
        log.warning("Failed to instantiate class %s" % class_str)
```

so for example, `filename="mock_test.py"` and `class_str="MockTest"`. That method is inside the `framework.py` class, inside `resources` and `integration.py` is inside `integration`. Something like this:

```
root / 
     resources /
            __init__.py
            framework.py
     integration /
            __init__.py
            integration.py
            testcases /
                __init__.py
                mock_test.py
```

So, from `integration` I execute that file, which contains

```
import resources.framework as framework
class Integration(framework.Framework):
     def __init__(self, args):
        super(Integration, self).__init__(args)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
2015-10-08 14:21:48 - Resources - WARNING - Failed to instantiate class MockTest
2015-10-08 14:21:48 - Resources - ERROR - No module named testcases.mock_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/resources/framework.py", line 92, in load_class
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named testcases.mock_test
2015-10-08 14:21:48 - Resources - INFO - Executing TestSuite: sample
```

I have an idea of what's going on. However I am unsure the best way to fix that, considering I want to use `framework.py` to other test frameworks I'm designing.
Could someone help me to fix this issue?

**** Updates ****:

- Overriding the method `load_class` in the child class `Integration` solved the problem. However the code is essentially the same.
- `self.root = "integration.testcases"`
- `module_path = "integration.testcases.mock_test"`
- `class_str="MockTest"`

Comment: You forgot to tell us what `self.root` is, since you're using that to build your path.

Comment: @philippe Very interesting approach! Do you by any chance have this code up on GitHub?

Comment: @idjaw I do not ... However I can scratch something and post on GitHub

Comment: Wow, thanks! Really appreciate that @philippe. I'm big on testing. So it really piqued my interest. :)